# How to access a container managed object from a class that is not managed by the container

Tags: java, jpa, cdi

Is there a way to access an object that is normally created and managed by the container from a class that is not created or managed by the container?  To put it another way code that can work with container managed instances of classes when there is a container and with regular POJO when there is no container?

**What is key to me is that the test class does not know if the class it is getting is coming from a container or just some stub.**

I may be old school but I want to use a configurable factory class to access my database.  When in production or integration testing it will return a container injected implementation of my DAL interface.  When unit testing I want to stub out the DAL and return static values.

Is this possible?

How can it be done?

Here is where I am at so far but still no joy...

Factory class

```
@Stateless
public class DALFactory
{
   @Inject
   private static DALInterface DAL;

   public static void init(String fqcn)
   {
      // use reflect to create unit test instance
   }

   public static DALInterface getDAL()
   {
      return DAL;
   }
}
```

Test class

```
public class test
{
   public void testDALAccess()
   {
      Table t = new Table(); // Instance of class representing a table
      DALFactory.getDAL().persist(t);
   }
}
```

This works just fine when I provide my testDAL because I call the init() with a FQCN but it fails miserably when I try to use container managed instances.

You can probably guess that I am somewhat new to CDI and JPA.

FYI the only reason I marked the `DALFactory` as `@Stateless` was so that it could be managed by the container when there was a container.

Comment: you might have a missconception, a major point of CDI is geting ride of the statics attributes.

Comment: Also, EJBs and CDIs are different technologies, albeit fairly similar. `@Stateless` is marking that class as an EJB, but `@Inject` is looking for a CDI injection. If this is working, that's fine, but you may find some undesired behaviour down the line. (You should either use `@SessionScoped` instead of `@Stateless`, or `@EJB` instead of `@Inject`, if you want to be consistent.)

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond OK, then how do you inject a test stub implementation of an interface for unit testing then?  I do not want to have to alter code before deploying to different environments because I want to move from stub to full implementation...

Comment: Injection should not be part of a unit test. Unit tests are about verifying the behaviour of a method or class (the "unit"); external dependencies are typically mocked with a tool like JMockit, Mockito or EasyMock, not injected. If you are referring to integration tests instead, then I would suggest they be run inside a container with a tool like Arquillian.

Comment: @dcsohl OK but how do I write code so that you do not need injection?  Take my specific example - how do I write a class so that I can test it without having to inject anything into it?  How do I test my "Test" class when the "testDALAccess()" method is called which is attempting to access the database but I don't have a container providing a database at the moment?

Comment: Rewriting your code and adding all sorts of utility methods *solely* for the purpose of testing is generally considered to be a bad idea. Nevertheless, you can use something like JMockit's [`Deencapsulation`](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Deencapsulation.html) class to do "manual" injection of your resources. I'd still recommend Arquillian though - I prefer to do integration tests in an environment as similar to production as I can. Arquillian will get you much closer than Deencapsulation.

Comment: I am not creating methods just for testing - the DAL interface is the same for testing and production.  When doing unit tests I simply spit the parameters of a DAL request to the screen and return some predefined value to test with.  I actually have a small utility that allows me to send a response from a file or from screen fields.  All without having a real database or container... just a basic JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I eventually did to get around the problem.  After I did this I was able to isolate the code that depends on injection and the related container so that I can test it without the container.

NOTE - I am still open to other ways of solving this problem such that I can test the same code with and without a container performing injection.

// DAL Factory

```
public class DALFactory
{
   private static DALInterface DAL;

   public static void setDAL(DALInterface di)
   {
      DAL = di;
   }

   public static void init(String fqcn)
   {
      // use reflect to create unit test instance
   }

   public static DALInterface getDAL()
   {
      return DAL;
   }
}
```

// Root injectable class, this has to be the top of the injectable tree

```
@Stateless
public MainClass
{
  @Inject
  ProdDAL dal;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct()
  {
      DALFactory.setDAL(new DALWrapper(this.dal));
  }
}
```

// DALWrapper

```
public DALWrapper implements DALInterface
{
   private ProdDAL dal;

   public DALWrapper(ProdDAL prodDAL)
   {
      this.dal = prodDal;
   }

... rest of interface goes here
}
```